# Pass parameters correctly to SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have code to insert data to SQL table.
The columns have such types:

```
@param1 datetime,
@param2 nvarchar(50),
@param3 int,
@param4 bit,
@param5 int,
@param6 bit,
@param7 bit,
@param8 varchar(20),
@param9 varchar(20)
```

This is my method:

```
try
{
    using (SqlCommand oleDbCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        // Set the command object properties
        oleDbCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        oleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oleDbCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[InsertRow]";
        // Add the input parameters to the parameter collection
        // m.param1 is of DateTime type, m.param2 of string type, m.param3 of int type, etc.
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", m.param1);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", m.param2);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", m.param3);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4", m.param4);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param5", m.param5);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param6", m.param6);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param7", m.param7);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param8", m.param8);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param9", m.param9);
        // Open the connection, execute the query and close the connection.
        oleDbCommand.Connection.Open();
        oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oleDbCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

I have two but related questions:

- am I passing parameters correctly? Or do I need casts? (please see the column types in the
  beginning of the question).
- how to correctly handle closing of database? In case also of some exception?

Comment: First point: don't use `AddWithValue`, it tries to guess the data type you are passing in.

Comment: Second point: Use `using` statement to close the Connection.

Comment: @DavidG: what to use instead can you give example? This code seems to work I seem to be reluctant to change it unless there is a need to

Comment: @georgem http://chrisrickard.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html

Comment: @georgem You should be using an using statement for `SqlConnection` also

Comment: @georgem You can find lots of examples [here is one](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand), also as DavidG recommended, don't use `AddWithValue` instead specify the SqlDbType explicitly.

Comment: @DavidG: I would appreciate if you could show some code how to use the other (the one which doesn't guess type automatically) method with my example?

Comment: @georgem The link I gave shows how to do it, have you even looked at it?

Comment: @georgem Yes it does, this is taken from the link `cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = _someID;`

Comment: @DavidG: I think Damith's solution is best below, isn't it?

Comment: You are expected to be able to take that link and make your own code though, don't expect people to write everything for you like @Damith kindly did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do as below

```
try
{   
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[InsertRow]", conn) { 
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
        conn.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = m.param1;
        command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = m.param2;
        command.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.Int).Value = m.param3;
        command.Parameters.Add("@param4", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = m.param4;
        command.Parameters.Add("@param5", SqlDbType.Int).Value = m.param5;
        command.Parameters.Add("@param6", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = m.param6;
        command.Parameters.Add("@param7", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = m.param7;
        command.Parameters.Add("@param8", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = m.param8;
        command.Parameters.Add("@param9", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = m.param9;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, first using doesn't need {}, I missed that NVarChar :)

Comment: @georgem use whatever you prefer, both ways are correct but I like this way because it is shorter and readable ( that's my idea only)

Comment: One more thing: I would **always** define an explicit **length** for any string-based parameters... (`SqlDbType.VarChar`, `SqlDbType.NVarChar`)

Comment: @marc_s Yes of Course, Included length as well

Answer (score 1):

AddWithValue tries to assigns the value by unboxing an object in the c# type based on the database field's type.

```
try
{
    using (var oleDbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Set the command object properties
        SqlCommand oleDbCommand = new SqlCommand()
        oleDbCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection;
        oleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oleDbCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[InsertRow]";
        // Add the input parameters to the parameter collection
        // m.param1 is of DateTime type, m.param2 of string type, m.param3 of int type, etc.
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", m.param1);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", m.param2);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", m.param3);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4", m.param4);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param5", m.param5);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param6", m.param6);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param7", m.param7);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param8", m.param8);
        oleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param9", m.param9);
        // Open the connection, execute the query and close the connection.
        oleDbCommand.Connection.Open();
        oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

using statement adds itself the correct connection handling after its use.

Comment: I putted the correct object instance in using clause and removed the closing logic. It's the correct way to make "using" of a DbConnection Object. Just to achieve the correct connection handling in case of exception thown.
Add with value, in my opinion, is a good way to bind parameters in a simple straight-forward way.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...