# Why do I get a "data type conversion error" with ExecuteNonQuery()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, winforms

Why do I get an error converting varchar into float conversion when I run this code?

I can't figure it out, please help.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim selected As Double
    Dim HourItem As Double
    Dim OverTimeRate As Double
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-F55AVQ6\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Db_Suncrest_Financial;Integrated Security=True")
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Db_Suncrest_FinancialDataSet.Tb_Suncrest_Financial_Payroll' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Tb_Suncrest_Financial_PayrollTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Db_Suncrest_FinancialDataSet.Tb_Suncrest_Financial_Payroll)

End Sub

Private Sub Employee_PositionComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Employee_PositionComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case Employee_PositionComboBox.SelectedItem
        Case "Banker"
            selected = 14.75
        Case "Bank Teller"
            selected = 10
        Case "Loan Processor"
            selected = 17.1
        Case "Mortgage Consultant"
            selected = 19.22
        Case "Investment Representative"
            selected = 19.31
        Case "Credit Analyst"
            selected = 19.88
        Case "Investment Banker"
            selected = 22.75
        Case "Relationship Manager"
            selected = 23.85
        Case "Financial Adviser"
            selected = 23.99
        Case "Financial Analyst"
            selected = 25.84
        Case "Asset Manager"
            selected = 26.86
        Case "Under Writer"
            selected = 27.56
        Case "Internal Auditor"
            selected = 28.79
        Case "Investment Banking Analyst"
            selected = 39.37
        Case "Loan Officer"
            selected = 43.18
    End Select

    Rate_Per_HourTextBox.Text = selected
End Sub

Private Sub Hours_WorkedComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Hours_WorkedComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case Hours_WorkedComboBox.SelectedItem
        Case "8"
            HourItem = 8
        Case "7"
            HourItem = 7
        Case "6"
            HourItem = 6
        Case "5"
            HourItem = 5
        Case "4"
            HourItem = 4
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub OverTime_RateComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OverTime_RateComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case OverTime_RateComboBox.SelectedItem
        Case "Normal Day"
            OverTimeRate = 1.25
        Case "Rest Day"
            OverTimeRate = 1.69
        Case "Special Non-Working Hoiday"
            OverTimeRate = 1.69
        Case "Special Non-Working Hoiday + Rest Day"
            OverTimeRate = 1.95
        Case "Regular Holliday"
            OverTimeRate = 2.6
        Case "Regular Holliday + Rest Day"
            OverTimeRate = 3.38
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Basic_PayTextBox.Text = HourItem * selected * 30
    OverTime_PayTextBox.Text = OverTimeRate * selected * OverTime_HoursTextBox.Text
    Gross_SalaryTextBox.Text = OverTime_PayTextBox.Text + Basic_PayTextBox.Text



    Total_Salary_W_TaxTextBox.Text = Gross_SalaryTextBox.Text * (0.0034 + 0.0363 + 0.01375)

    Date_TimeTextBox.Text = Format(Now, "General Date")


End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    connection.Open()
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("Insert into Tb_Suncrest_Financial_Payroll(Employee_Id_No, Employee_Name, Employee_Position, Residence, Date_Time, Hours_Worked, Rate_Per_Hour, 
                                   Basic_Pay, OverTime_Hours, OverTime_Rate, OverTime_Pay, Gross_Salary, SSS, Pagibig, Philhealth, Total_Salary_W_Tax) 
                                   Values(
                                   '" & Employee_Id_NoTextBox.Text & "', '" & Employee_NameTextBox.Text & "', '" & Employee_PositionComboBox.Text & "', '" & ResidenceTextBox.Text & "', '" & Date_TimeTextBox.Text & "',
                                   '" & Hours_WorkedComboBox.Text & "', '" & Rate_Per_HourTextBox.Text & "', '" & Basic_PayTextBox.Text & "', '" & OverTime_HoursTextBox.Text & "', '" & OverTime_RateComboBox.Text & "',
                                   '" & OverTime_PayTextBox.Text & "', '" & Gross_SalaryTextBox.Text & "', '" & SSSTextBox.Text & "', '" & PagibigTextBox.Text & "', '" & PhilhealthTextBox.Text & "', '" & Total_Salary_W_TaxTextBox.Text & "')", connection)



    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_Id_No", SqlDbType.Int)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_Position", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Residence", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours_Worked", SqlDbType.Int)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate_Per_Hour", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Basic_Pay", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OverTime_Hours", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OverTime_Rate", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OverTime_Pay", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gross_Salary", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSS", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pagibig", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Philhealth", SqlDbType.Float)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Salary_W_Tax", SqlDbType.Float)


    If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Added")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Added")
    End If
    connection.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You need to do more reading on how ADO.NET works and how to add parameters. You're not adding any parameters in your SQL code, which leaves you open to all manner of issues, and then you add parameters incorrectly in your VB code. Learn how to use parameters properly. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my own instruction on that.

Comment: yes, i learned a bunch of do's and don'ts with your article thanks, but stillhave a new problem, an error comes out and saying must declare scalar variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the ideas presented by @Charlieface excellent answer.

A few points in addition.

It is very common for ID fields to be identity fields (auto-number) Check your database.
If this is the case then you would not include E`mployee_ID` in the fields list, Values list of add anything to the parameters collection for that field. In your case this appears to be a payroll table so perhaps `Employee_ID` is a foreign key to an employees table elsewhere. In this case, the code is fine.

Users are apt to enter anything is a `TextBox`. I strongly suggest that you validate all the input for numbers and dates with `.TryParse` before attempting the insert.

Never present a message box while a connection is open. Connections are precious resources and should be opened directly before the `.Execute...` and closed as soon as possible with `End Using`.

There appears to be several calculated fields that do not need to be stored at all but storage is cheap and it will probably make other queries simpler.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    Dim Sql = "Insert into Tb_Suncrest_Financial_Payroll(Employee_Id_No, Employee_Name, Employee_Position, Residence, Date_Time, Hours_Worked, Rate_Per_Hour, 
                               Basic_Pay, OverTime_Hours, OverTime_Rate, OverTime_Pay, Gross_Salary, SSS, 
                               Pagibig, Philhealth, Total_Salary_W_Tax) 
                               Values(
                               @Employee_Id_No, @Employee_Name, @Employee_Position, @Residence, @Hours_Worked,@Rate_Per_Hour, 
                               @Basic_PayTextBox, @OverTime_Hours, @OverTime_Rate, @Gross_Salary, @SSS,
                               @Pagibig, @Philhealth, @Total_Salary_W_Tax);"
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            command As New SqlCommand(Sql, connection)
        With command.Parameters
            .Add("@Employee_Id_No", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Employee_Id_NoTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@Employee_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Employee_NameTextBox.Text
            .Add("@Employee_Position", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Employee_Position.Text
            .Add("@Residence", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ResidenceTextBox.Text
            .Add("@Date_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = CDate(Date_TimeTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@Hours_Worked", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Hours_WorkedComboBox.Text)
            .Add("@Rate_Per_Hour", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(Rate_Per_HourTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@Basic_Pay", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(Basic_PayTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@OverTime_Hours", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(OverTime_HoursTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@OverTime_Rate", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(OverTime_RateComboBox.Text)
            .Add("@OverTime_Pay", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(OverTime_PayTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@Gross_Salary", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(Gross_SalaryTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@SSS", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(SSSTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@Pagibig", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(PagibigTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@Philhealth", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(PhilhealthTextBox.Text)
            .Add("@Total_Salary_W_Tax", SqlDbType.Float).Value = CDbl(Total_Salary_W_TaxTextBox.Text)
        End With
        connection.Open()
        RetVal = command.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    If RetVal = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Added")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Added")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Set varchar lengths also: `...SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = ...`

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26462365/14868997) as to how to call SQL Server correctly.

---

Well, instead of using SQL parameters properly, you have just concatenated the values directly into the query. For example, although you have added a parameter:

```cs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_Id_No", SqlDbType.Int)
```

you are not actually using it:

```cs
'" & Employee_Id_NoTextBox.Text & "'
```

Instead you need to write your `insert` like this, no concatenation needed:

```cs
Values(@Employee_Id_No, @Employee_Name ...
```

---

See also [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjpgbvx7aLuAhWHQkEAHfSxDo8QFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dbdelta.com%2Faddwithvalue-is-evil%2F&usg=AOvVaw2RJU8Yk5ipRJaCUJ2JPeZN) by Dan Guzman about why not to use `AddWithValue`, especially for `varchar` columns.
You should use

```
Add("@Employee_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, insert_column_length).Value = Employee_Id_NoTextBox.Text;
```

---

You should also not cache connection and command objects. Dispose them with `using` blocks.

---

*EDIT*

You also need to cast your `Text` values to the various types, for example `CInt(Employee_Id_NoTextBox.Text)`

Comment: You beat me to it ;-). Adding that `AddWithValue` expects the parameter name and parameter value rather than SqlDbType. The code in the question will result in strange and undesired behavior when ADO.NET attempts to coerce the type object into a SqlDbType and value.

Comment: Sorry forgot to credit you fixed now :-) I've quoted your article probably 3-4 times in the past week alone. [Here's another guy five min later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65760067/how-to-fix-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-th)The last point about `using` blocks is also important.

Comment: so you mean  don't need concatenation? but why?

Comment: See the answer I quoted https://stackoverflow.com/a/26462365/14868997 When you pass a parameter `@Employee_Name`, you use that parameter name directly in the query

Comment: @Jm25E, with a parameterized query, the CommandText is a constant literal that contains the statement with parameter names. No concatenation is needed because the parameter values are passed separately in the parameter collection.

Comment: But now i have another problem which is the employee_id with a value of int in database, but when I use the vb.net project to save it gives me error : string can't be converted into int

Comment: You need to cast the values on the VB side first, see edit

Comment: yes now it look like this: .Add("@Employee_Id_No", SqlDbType.Int, 0).Value = CInt(Employee_Id_NoTextBox.Text) that Causes another error: Must declare scalar variable "@Employee_Id_No"

Comment: Remove the `, 0` you don't need `length` for an `int` parameter. Can you [edit] your post with your current code, as it should work now.