# Trying to update data in C# does not work

Tags: c#

I have a form which updates data. Query is executing but not updating the data. What's wrong? How to fix this?

It was working when I had concatenation but I changed it to parameters and now it's not working

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            if (SId.Text == "" || SellName.Text == "" || SellAge.Text == "" || SellPhone.Text == "" || SellPass.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing info");
            }
            
            string query = "UPDATE Sellers SET [SellerName] = @Name, [SellerAge] = @Age, [SellerPhone] = @Phone, [SellerPassword] = @Pass WHERE [SellerId] = @Id";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SId.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SellName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", SellAge.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", SellPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", SellPass.Text);

            Con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Update successful!");

            SId.Text = "";
            SellName.Text = "";
            SellPhone.Text = "";
            SellPass.Text = "";
            SellAge.Text = "";

            Con.Close();

            populate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? You should use `using` blocks for connection and command objects, and do not use `AddWithValue` instead use `Add` with correct parameter types and sizes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a "data type conversion error" with ExecuteNonQuery()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759681/why-do-i-get-a-data-type-conversion-error-with-executenonquery)

Comment: I guess you get some expection or some error some where please include that if so

Comment: You should add a return after `MessageBox.Show("Information missing");`. You should also check the return of `int ExecuteNonQuery()` which indicates the number of rows affected, instead of assuming everything is fine with `MessageBox.Show("Update successful!");`. Also, have you tried the query using an SQL browser? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a connection for the shortest time possible. Instead of conection.Open() use cmd.connection.Open(). I recommend  to use this code:

```
     var result=0;
      using (var con= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
       
           var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SId.Text); //??? if @Id is int or varchar?

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SellName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", SellAge.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", SellPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", SellPass.Text);
             cmd.Connection.Open();
            result=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
         if(result>0) MessageBox.Show("Update successful!");
         else ....error

            .... your code
```

I marked with ?? your @Id input parameter. I have some doubts that it is a string type. Check again. If it is int or any another type you will have to convert SId.Text to this type before to create a parameter.The same about @Age.