# What is the datatype for Date in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have been getting this error while trying to use DateTimePicker to insert the current date and time into a table. I tried using `Date` and `datetime` datatypes with SQL Server, but it seem not to fix this error.

[image]

```
private void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (isFormValid())
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Report this Driver?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into reportinfo values('" + txtDriverName.Text + "','" + txtLPNO.Text + "','" + txtCODENO.Text + "''" + txtReason.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()+ "');", sqlCon);

                    int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (temp > 0)
                    {
                       MessageBox.Show("Cab Driver Successfully Reported", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't Report Driver Please Check the current fields", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error inserting data" + ex, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

                txtDriverName.Clear();
                txtLPNO.Clear();
                txtCODENO.Clear();

                this.OnLoad(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool isFormValid()
    {
        if (txtDriverName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtLPNO.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill All Required Fields", "Required Fields are Empty",  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
}
```

Comment: Whatever it is, you shouldn't be concatenating values direct into a query, that leads to the dark side of SQL injection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass parameters correctly to SqlCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461949/pass-parameters-correctly-to-sqlcommand)

Comment: Consider what happens if someone enters `',0); DROP DATABASE MyDb; SELECT ('` into txtReason

Comment: No still the same

Comment: Issues with your code you need to sort out before asking further: **1.** Specify column names to be inserted into in the `insert` statement **2.** Parameterize the query, pass parameters with correct datatypes *and lengths for strings* **3.** Cast values to those parameter types **4.** Dispose connection and command with `using` blocks. Do NOT cache them

Comment: That is absolutely the wrong way to combine data into a query (and has been so for a very long time) further, you are converting the DTP value to string which is wrong if you are in fact using a Date column in the DB.

Comment: The error message is very very clear. `Column name or number of supplies values does not match table definition`. See Charlie's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the table structure for `reportinfo`

As mentioned by @Squirrel, the columns don;t match.  You are trying to insert into 5 columns:

```
txtDriverName.Text + "','" + txtLPNO.Text + "','" + txtCODENO.Text + "''" + txtReason.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()
```

but obviously the number of columns in the table do NOT match this.

Also as mentioned, you need to parameterise the query to avoid SQL injection.